# Free publicly available 3D faces morphable models

Tags: data-request, machine-learning, faces

I've found two excellent models. The first one is linear face model of Basel university called [Basel Face Model](http://gravis.dmi.unibas.ch/publications/2009/BFModel09.pdf), which includes different face shapes. Another one is bilinear model [FaceWarehouse](http://www.kunzhou.net/2012/facewarehouse-tr.pdf), which includes not only different shapes, but expressions as well. The problem is: I don't know whether it's available for ordinary students; also seems like it doesn't contain textures.

The aim of my Master's thesis is to implement a better algorithm for 3D facial surface inverse rendering than existent ones. I've understood that I'll not achieve good results without different facial expressions, so I need a good dataset for further work.

Do you know free publicly available morphable 3D face models?
I need it to contain models with full correspondence of vertices in order to have linear space of faces with different expressions. Would be nice to get textured high-resolution model (tens of thousands vertices).

Though, what another names of such models do you know except "liniar model", "bilinear model", "morphable model" and "generative model" (you may provide your variants in comments)?

Comment: FaceWarehouse is pretty clear you can access their data: "We make all RGBD scans, feature points and the fitted meshes available for academic research purposes. However, as human face is very personal, we only send the data to approved researchers. To obtain a copy, please send an email to kunzhou at acm doc org stating"

Comment: @albert Yes, I've pointed to this database in my question and also sent a request to Professor Kun Zhou. Though, as I've noticed, I'm not sure whether this model is available for single students with degree lower than PhD, and I didn't see textured models in their demos (textures were taken from images, not from original faces, as I understand).